# which is night of Laylatul Qadr?

Tags: laylat-al-qadr

As in Islam after maghrib, the next day starts so the 26th of Fast evening will be the 27th which could be one of Laylatul Qadr?

Is it true or will 27th fast evening will be 27th Laylatul Qadr?

Answer (score 2):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

Count starts on the last day of Shabaan. At the end of Asr, during the Maghrib, after Crescent is sighted then the night after Magrib is the 1st night of Shahri Ramadaan.

As of this moment Shahri Ramadaan starts

- 1st night then 1st day (fast)
- 2nd night then 2nd day (fast)
- 3rd night then 3rd day (fast)
- ...
- **26th night then 26th day (fast)**
- **27th night then 27th day (fast)**
- ...
- 30th night then 30th day (fast) (like the last day of Shabaan at the end of Asr, during the Maghrib, after Crescent is sighted then the night after Magrib is the 1st night of Shawwaal.)

As of this moment Shawwaal starts

- 1st night then 1st day (Salatul Eid after Fajr, Duha time)
- 2nd night then 2nd day
- 3rd night then 3rd day
- ...

**So you fast the 26th day then next night is 27th night of Shahri Ramadan.**

Comment: so to clarify, today here is it is 26th Ramadan, so today evening will be laylatul qadr as tomorrow will be 27th Fast

Comment: If today is 26th day of Shahri Ramadan in your area then, yes, the following night is 27th night of Shahri Ramadan. The next day you will be fasting 27th day.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. 26th fast evening will be 27th Laylatul Qadr.